# Issue When Trying to Install Windows (hard disk related)

Tags: boot, windows-10, disk

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and after several weeks I felt uncomfortable with Ubuntu and decided to go back to Windows. Windows installation is okay until I noticed something odd.

It takes too long to install Windows. After the "completing installation" step is finished, my laptop will reboot and then it says...

> A disk read error occured, Press CTRL + ALT + DEL to restart

So I decided to install Ubuntu again, I've searched for fix around the internet but no success. I've tried to change the table type to MS-DOS, but not success.

Also, I noticed it takes longer time to install Windows than Linux OS, I've tried Mint and Ubuntu, they had the same installation speed compared to Windows that took up to 8 hours.

Is something wrong with my hard drive? Oh, I also formatted my hard drive (with Windows 10 in it) before installing Ubuntu.

Ubuntu works perfectly fine in my laptop.

Here's a GParted screenshot:
[image]

Comment: please can you change the title of your question to reflect that this is a disk issue and that you are not asking for help installing windows 10, you will get much more positive attention this way

Answer (score 1):

Boot from an Ubuntu bootable media, and check the hard disk for errors. At least take a look to the S.M.A.R.T. values with the Disk Utility. If it isn't installed:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility
```

If everything looks OK, clean your hard disk with `dd`, assuming that the hard disk is `/dev/sda`:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda
```

Depending of the size of the disk it will take a while. After finish, switch off the computer and reboot with your Windows 10 installation media, and install that OS. It should work.

Comment: Boot Ubuntu in live mode, and run Gparted and see what's going on, take a screenshot if possible and add it to the question.
And I'd recommend you change the title of the question or you will be downvoted so much!

Comment: What does sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda do?

Comment: @kokolacio: it zeroes out the full surface of the disk. It leaves no leftovers (it will be just like rolling out from factory - kind of, simplified) on the surface.

Comment: There's actually no point in overwriting the whole disk with zeros unless you want to 1) check that all drive sectors are still writeable or 2) make sure that no one can scrape any left-over information from your hard-drive (e. g. when selling your computer to a stranger). To get rid of the previous partitions and partition table simply create a new one with your favourite partition manager. Also `dd` on a typical HDD or SSD will take ages without a reasonable block size like `bs=8M` or something like that.

Comment: I followes your guide and still, no success. "A disk read error occured"...

Comment: This looks like a dead drive.